# add files in to webroot/files

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a problem, I have view file, but how to save these uploads in to webroot/files. Im using CakePHP:

This is my uploadfile.ctp

```
echo $this->Form->create('YourModel', array('type' => 'file','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'));

echo $this->Form->input('files.', array('type' => 'file', 'multiple'));

echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
```

I dont know where to start in Controller, I really need these files in to webroot/files, thankyou !

At the moment I have in Controller:

```
public function uploadFile() {

            if ($this->request->is('UploadFile')) {

           $tmp_name=$this->request->data['UploadFile']['image'];
           $filename = time().$this->request->data['UploadFile']['image']['name'];
           if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name['tmp_name'],WWW_ROOT."/files".$filename)) {

          } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('There was a problem uploading file. Please try again.','default',array('class'=>'alert alert-danger'));

        }
       }

        }
```

**UPDATE**

Now I have updated view file and updated Controller, where I want to upload multiple files, but only one file going in to files folder.

**View file:**

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('uploadFile', array( 'type' => 'file'));
?>

    <div class="input_fields_wrap">

        <label for="uploadFilefiles"></label>
        <input type="file" name="data[files]" id="uploadFilefiles">

    </div>

<button type="button" class="add_field_button">+</button> <br><br>

    <form name="frm1" method="post" onsubmit="return greeting()">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

<?php
echo $this->Html->script('addFile');
```

**Controller File:**

```
public function uploadFile() {
        $filename = '';
            if ($this->request->is('post')) { // checks for the post values
                $uploadData = $this->data['files'];
                print_r($this->data['files']); die;
                if ( $uploadData['size'] == 0 || $uploadData['error'] !== 0) { // checks for the errors and size of the uploaded file
                    echo "Failide maht kokku ei tohi olla üle 5MB";
                    return false;
                }
                $filename = basename($uploadData['name']); // gets the base name of the uploaded file
                $uploadFolder = WWW_ROOT. 'files';  // path where the uploaded file has to be saved
                $filename = $filename; // adding time stamp for the uploaded image for uniqueness
                $uploadPath =  $uploadFolder . DS . $filename;
                if( !file_exists($uploadFolder) ){
                    mkdir($uploadFolder); // creates folder if  not found
                }
                if (!move_uploaded_file($uploadData['tmp_name'], $uploadPath)) {
                    return false;
                } 
                echo "Sa sisestasid faili(d): $filename";

            }

    }
```

**and this Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 3;
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap");
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button");

    var x = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append("<div><input type='file' name='data[files]' id='uploadFilefiles'/><a href='#' class='remove_field'>Kustuta</a></div>");
        }
     });

      $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
        })
});
```

How I can upload all 3 files in to `webroot/files` folder ?

Comment: What I exacly want to do : If I click Sumbit, then save these files in to Webroot/Files.

Answer (score 1):

```
try this code , this is a demo code and its is work on my server

  <div class="col-sm-12">
              <?php echo $this->Form->file('Feature.image.',array('class'=>'form-control','label'=>false,'div'=>false,'required','multiple'));?>
              </div>
```

[image]

if ($this->request->is('post')) {

```
        $data=$this->request->data['Feature']['image'];
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
         $this->request->data['Feature']['image'][$key]['name'];

       $tmp_name=$this->request->data['Feature']['image'][$key];

      $filename = time().$this->request->data['Feature']['image'][$key]['name'];

       if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name['tmp_name'],WWW_ROOT."/img/feature/".$filename)) {

        $updatefile= $this->Feature->updateAll(
                array('Feature.image' => "'$filename'"),
                array('Feature.id' => $id,'Feature.userid'=>$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id'))
            );
       if($updatefile==1){
        $file = new File(WWW_ROOT . 'img/feature/'.$featuredata['Feature']['image'], false, 0777);
        if($file->delete()) {
          $this->Session->setFlash('File uploaded successfuly uploaded.','default',array('class'=>'alert alert-success'),'success'); 
          return $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Users','action'=>'featureshow')) ;

         }

       }

      } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash('There was a problem uploading file. Please try again.','default',array('class'=>'alert alert-danger'));
      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: please can you elaborate ,if am right you can upload via javascript

Comment: My view file is so much different from yours, this controller is not working for me

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68398/discussion-on-answer-by-vikram-sharma-add-files-in-to-webroot-files).

Answer (score 0):

No, of course you do not need a table.
I guess you are looking for something like this in your controller:

```
                foreach($this->request->data['files'] as $file){
                            move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . 'uploads/' . $uuid . '.jpg');
                }
```

Comment: mm, its for images only ?

Comment: But something like this im lookig for yes .. I want to do this in easy way, Just this view file, and these files going to webroot/files folder.

Comment: its the same. updated. just forgot to rename a variable

Comment: `Undefined index: files [APP\Controller\UploadFileController.php, line 6]` and `Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP\Controller\UploadFileController.php, line 6]`

Comment: add some files and add this to your controller:
    `die(print_r($this->request->data));`

you have to replace this: `$this->request->data['files']`
to something like this:
`$this->request->data['YourModel']['files']`
can't test it right now

Answer (score 0):

Use this:-

```
$uploadedFile = $this->request->params['form']['uploadCsv']['tmp_name'];
$dir = WWW_ROOT . 'files/';
if ( !is_dir( $dir ) ) {
    mkdir($dir);
    chmod( $dir , 777);
}
$fileName = 'file_' . date( 'Y_m_d_h_i_s', time() );
move_uploaded_file( $uploadedFile, $dir. $fileName . '.csv' );
```

This is a sample code which works on my server, and should work for you as well